# Physicality of a 2 Qubits

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information

What is the physical description of two qubits? If the data is reprented in the polarity of light (a common example) are two qubits two separate photons of light, or is there somehow more data on a single photon?

Answer (score 2):

A *qubit* is an abstract description that can be applied to **any** physical quantum system that has a two-dimensional state space, just as a *bit* is an abstract description of any classical system that has two states. The most common examples are spin-1/2 particles (like electrons or particular types of ions, where the two orthogonal states are, for example, "spin-up" and "spin-down") and photons (where the two orthogonal states are, for example, "vertically polarized" or "horizontally polarized", or alternatively, "right-handed circularly polarized" or "left-handed circularly polarized"). Other physical implementations of the qubit exist, though, like nitrogen vacancies in diamond and certain phenomena in superconductors.

As such, there is no single physical description of a single qubit; therefore, there can be no single physical description for a two-qubit system.

If your qubit implementation is a polarized photon, then the two-qubit system would consist of two photons (plus whatever apparatus you're using to get them to interact with each other in a way that does useful things).